# Specify different max body size per location

Tags: nginx

So my main nginx configuration file specifies a max body size to be fairly small:

```
http {
  client_body_buffer_size  4096K;
  client_header_buffer_size 4k;
  client_max_body_size 4096k;
  large_client_header_buffers 2 4k;
}
```

This is for security reasons as I use Nginx mostly to reverse proxy requests to RESTful APIs. However, I have an admin panel where I want to allow users to upload images. I would therefor like to increase the allowed image size for a specific location of /admin.

I tried:

```
location /api {
  proxy_pass http://api-cluster;
}

location /admin {
  proxy_pass http://admin-cluster;

  # we need to increase this so images can be uploaded in admin panel
  client_body_buffer_size  4096K;
  client_header_buffer_size 4k;
  client_max_body_size 4096k;
  large_client_header_buffers 2 4k;
}
```

This does not work however.

```
Reloading nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] "client_header_buffer_size" directive is not allowed here
```

Any idea how to solve this little problem?

Comment: That directive is only valid in the [http and server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_buffer_size) contexts. it's not allowed in locations.

Comment: @MarcB I figured that out. I am asking if there is, maybe, some other way to achieve the desired outcome.

Comment: Make admin server. Admin.example.com and define desired limits there